# Silly doubt about relationship between Levi-Civita Connections and Koszul Form

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

In this paper [1] the author wrote and interresting relationship between differential geometry objects (the Levi-civita connection and Koszul form) by means of a musical isomorphism [2] (roughly speaking, the operation of Rasing and Lowering indexes of tensors [3]):

$$\nabla_{X}Y = \mathcal{K}(X,Y,\cdot)^{\#}   \tag{1}$$

Well, this relationship is somekind of theorem? (I did a quick search and I didn't found anything)

$$* * *$$

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5303

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices

Comment: The basic ideas are in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry

Comment: This either follows as a theorem from the definition of the Levi-Civita connection given in Wikipedia, or it can be taken to be an alternate but less intuitive definition of the L-C connection.